# Change Button text font size in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I'm starting out with Codename One (in Netbeans 8.2 on MacOS El Capitan) and I'd like to change the font size of a Button text. I'm using a default theme in an IOS emulator and the button text looks too large.

When I go into the theme file (theme.res) in the project, I can change the font for Button for each of the four styles from SYSTEM-PLAIN-MEDIUM to SYSTEM-PLAIN-SMALL but that change seems to do nothing. If I programmatically get the style from the button, I can set the font but then I have to set the font color and size for each of the 4 styles.

Is there an easy way to change the size of the button text so it isn't so large?

Is there a way to do this programmatically, ie in code? Or is it much simpler to do it in the theme.res file? How exactly? It sure would be nice to have a way to change just the size of whatever font is being used without having to specifically change the font.

Comment: Always comment, upvote or "accept as answer" if your question is answered on StackOverflow... remember other developers go out of their way to provide you help and the worst you could do to them is use their solution then ignore them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your changes have no effect is because at the bottom of `SYSTEM-PLAIN-MEDIUM`, `True Type` is set to either `native: MainRegular` or `native: MainLight`, this means you are using the native font which looks good on mobile devices.

To change this, you will have to change `TrueType Size` which is directly below and was set to some millimetres by default... or change the `True Type` font to blank if your want to keep using the System font.

Since you are a beginner, I will suggest you do most of your styling in the GUI Builder (theme.res). Once you understand how Codename One design works, then you can move to a more advanced method, which is styling in code.

If you prefer styling in code like me and feel you are ready for that, you can check [this library](https://github.com/diamondobama/cn1-Helper) out. It's a small library I wrote to do most of the typographical styling that could be done in the Gui Builder.

You can add it to your project by going to **Codename One Settings** then -> **Extensions** and search for `Helper`. After adding it, Right-click your project -> Codename One -> Refresh cn1lib files and you can start using it. See basic usage on that Github page.

Also, have a look at how you can use the [new GUI Builder](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-the-new-gui-builder.html).